# FileSystemWatcher - folder rename problem

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

When the folder is renamed the `filesystemwatcher` object continues to watch the new folder even through the name has changed.

For example,during the day, my data files are in the `data` folder and the 
`filewatcher` listens to this folder.

But in some scenarios the data folder is renamed to `dataBKP` due to a backup being taken. A new data folder is created again with the name `data` and includes initialized data files.

In this case the `filewatcher` starts to watch `dataBKP` folder until the application is restarted.

I logged the path property of `filewatcher` and it is still `data` but it is watching `dataBKP` because of the folder rename.

Any advice?

Comment: When the old *(old compare to folder rename)* comparer still watches the old directory, I would add a watcher on parent directory *(with a filter for 'data' folder)* and when the 'data' folder get renamed, or deleted, close the old watcher and in case new 'data' folder is created, start new watcher for new 'data' folder.

Comment: how can i get the event of getting "data" folder renamed.if i know in run time, i can reinitialized filewatcher object.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher to watch the directory specified at run time. The component is set to watch for changes in LastWrite and LastAccess time, the creation, deletion, or renaming of text files in the directory.

Comment: Pretty sure it is by design, the underlying ReadDirectoryChangesW() winapi function documents "This buffer is associated with the directory handle until it is closed".  The directory handle does not change when the directory is renamed.  If want to detect the rename then you also need to watch the parent directory.